# A word used to describe something that is popular and generic

Tags: single-word-requests, popularity

There is a word that for some reason I forgot.

It is used to describe something that is popular, generic and people maybe only do it because it is popular.

Like when you see someone’s playlist and realize they are just straight from the radio and his taste in music is very .....

Answer (score 5):

**Mainstream** could work here. A definition according to Merriam-Webster is:

> a prevailing current or direction of activity or influence

The word is often used in the case of mass media and the [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainstream) has some more information, including a base definition:

> Mainstream is current thought that is widespread. It includes all popular culture and media culture, typically disseminated by mass media. It is to be distinguished from subcultures and countercultures, and at the opposite extreme are cult followings and fringe theories.

Comment: The wiki entry also notes that it can be used as a pejorative, which seems very in line with what the question is expressing.

Answer (score 1):

"...his taste in music is very **pedestrian**."?